# Struts or Springs for Batch processing

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, batch-processing

Currently I am working on some application which would later require batch functionality module since I have not yet started that module I need to know which (Struts or Springs) has the best Framework for batch processing.

Comment: I'd assume you mean spring-mvc vs struts2 for batch processing? I've got bad news neither are for batch processing. What ever batch processing framework you pick will be largely unrelated to the web tier and so it wouldn't make much of a difference what you use.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Springs is better for batch processing as it provide complete spring batch framework for batch processing. Apart from this whatever you are running in struts can be easily integrated to spring frameworks.

Comment: can you please specify the difference between them on the base of efficiency like time constraint, memory cost, exception handling etc

Comment: Well strtus2 is a web framework... Spring-batch is a framework for batch processing. Spring-mvc is yet another completely different framework. Spring frameworks use spring core functionality (Dependency injection/AOP). Spring core functionality can be trivially integrated into Struts2. To compare struts2 to spring-batch is ridiculous, to answer the absurd deserves a down vote.